# Create Folder in other Mailbox with EWS API

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, impersonation

I try to create a contact folder in an other mailbox. Since Powershell can't do this I downloaded a c# sample over this MSDN site:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/exchange/Exchange-2013-Create-35e4948c/view/Discussions#content

Then I modified the createFolder_CS.cs to this:

```
    class Ex15_CreateFolder_CS
    {
    static ExchangeService service = Service.ConnectToService(UserDataFromConsole.GetUserData(), new TraceListener());

    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        CreateFolder(service, "Test", WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot);

        Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Press or select Enter...");
        Console.Read();
        }

    static void CreateFolder(ExchangeService service, string DisplayName, WellKnownFolderName DestinationFolder)
        {
        // Instantiate the Folder object.
        Folder folder = new ContactsFolder(service);

        // Specify the name of the new folder.
        folder.DisplayName = DisplayName;

        // Create the new folder in the specified destination folder.
        folder.Save(DestinationFolder);

        Console.WriteLine("Folder created:" + folder.DisplayName);
        }
    }
```

After the change I started the program. I entered my e-mail and the password and it created the contact folder in my mailbox. But when I use a different e-mail address the program did not work.

I compiled it and started the exe-file as (other user) domain/exchange-admin but it still did not work for another mailbox.

So I read something about a ImpersonatedUserId but this is already included in the program.

Maybe you can give me some tipps how to make this working since I am a starter at c#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is you not telling it what Mailbox you want to save the new folder in. You need to use the FolderId overload to specify this or its always going to save it to the Mailbox of the credentials its running under eg modify you sub like

```
        static void CreateFolder(ExchangeService service, string DisplayName, WellKnownFolderName DestinationFolder,String TargetMailboxSMTPAddress)
    {
    // Instantiate the Folder object.
    Folder folder = new ContactsFolder(service);

    // Specify the name of the new folder.
    folder.DisplayName = DisplayName;


     FolderId ParentFolder = new FolderId(DestinationFolder,TargetMailboxSMTPAddress);
    // Create the new folder in the specified destination folder.
    folder.Save(ParentFolder);

    Console.WriteLine("Folder created:" + folder.DisplayName);
    }
```

If you want to use Impersonation then you just need to add One more line in the code

```
service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress,TargetMailboxSMTPAddress);
```

You will need to be assigned the ApplicationImpersonation RBAC role to use this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb204095(v=exchg.140).aspx

If your creating a console app to run in poweshell I would suggest you just use the Managed API in Powershell eg here a script module that will create Folders in Mailbox using the Managed API

```
function Connect-Exchange{ 
    param( 
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$MailboxName,
        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)] [PSCredential]$Credentials
    )  
    Begin
         {
        Load-EWSManagedAPI

        ## Set Exchange Version  
        $ExchangeVersion = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2013_SP1

        ## Create Exchange Service Object  
        $service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService($ExchangeVersion)  

        ## Set Credentials to use two options are availible Option1 to use explict credentials or Option 2 use the Default (logged On) credentials  

        #Credentials Option 1 using UPN for the windows Account  
        #$psCred = Get-Credential  
        $creds = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Credentials.UserName.ToString(),$Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().password.ToString())  
        $service.Credentials = $creds      
        #Credentials Option 2  
        #service.UseDefaultCredentials = $true  
         #$service.TraceEnabled = $true
        ## Choose to ignore any SSL Warning issues caused by Self Signed Certificates  

        Handle-SSL  

        ## Set the URL of the CAS (Client Access Server) to use two options are availbe to use Autodiscover to find the CAS URL or Hardcode the CAS to use  

        #CAS URL Option 1 Autodiscover  
        $service.AutodiscoverUrl($MailboxName,{$true})  
        Write-host ("Using CAS Server : " + $Service.url)   

        #CAS URL Option 2 Hardcoded  

        #$uri=[system.URI] "https://casservername/ews/exchange.asmx"  
        #$service.Url = $uri    

        ## Optional section for Exchange Impersonation  

        #$service.ImpersonatedUserId = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress, $MailboxName) 
        if(!$service.URL){
            throw "Error connecting to EWS"
        }
        else
        {       
            return $service
        }
    }
}

function Load-EWSManagedAPI{
    param( 
    )  
    Begin
    {
        ## Load Managed API dll  
        ###CHECK FOR EWS MANAGED API, IF PRESENT IMPORT THE HIGHEST VERSION EWS DLL, ELSE EXIT
        $EWSDLL = (($(Get-ItemProperty -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Path Registry::$(Get-ChildItem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services'|Sort-Object Name -Descending| Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Name)).'Install Directory') + "Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll")
        if (Test-Path $EWSDLL)
            {
            Import-Module $EWSDLL
            }
        else
            {
            "$(get-date -format yyyyMMddHHmmss):"
            "This script requires the EWS Managed API 1.2 or later."
            "Please download and install the current version of the EWS Managed API from"
            "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=255472"
            ""
            "Exiting Script."
            exit
            } 
    }
}

function Handle-SSL{
    param( 
    )  
    Begin
    {
        ## Code From http://poshcode.org/624
        ## Create a compilation environment
        $Provider=New-Object Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider
        $Compiler=$Provider.CreateCompiler()
        $Params=New-Object System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters
        $Params.GenerateExecutable=$False
        $Params.GenerateInMemory=$True
        $Params.IncludeDebugInformation=$False
        $Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.DLL") | Out-Null

$TASource=@'
  namespace Local.ToolkitExtensions.Net.CertificatePolicy{
    public class TrustAll : System.Net.ICertificatePolicy {
      public TrustAll() { 
      }
      public bool CheckValidationResult(System.Net.ServicePoint sp,
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate cert, 
        System.Net.WebRequest req, int problem) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
'@ 
        $TAResults=$Provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource($Params,$TASource)
        $TAAssembly=$TAResults.CompiledAssembly

        ## We now create an instance of the TrustAll and attach it to the ServicePointManager
        $TrustAll=$TAAssembly.CreateInstance("Local.ToolkitExtensions.Net.CertificatePolicy.TrustAll")
        [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy=$TrustAll

        ## end code from http://poshcode.org/624

    }
}

function Get-FolderFromPath{
    param (
            [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$FolderPath,
            [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$MailboxName,
            [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true)] [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService]$service,
            [Parameter(Position=3, Mandatory=$false)] [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet]$PropertySet
          )
    process{
        ## Find and Bind to Folder based on Path  
        #Define the path to search should be seperated with \  
        #Bind to the MSGFolder Root  
        $folderid = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::MsgFolderRoot,$MailboxName)   
        $tfTargetFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)  
        #Split the Search path into an array  
        $fldArray = $FolderPath.Split("\") 
         #Loop through the Split Array and do a Search for each level of folder 
        for ($lint = 1; $lint -lt $fldArray.Length; $lint++) { 
            #Perform search based on the displayname of each folder level 
            $fvFolderView = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(1) 
            if(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($PropertySet)){
                $fvFolderView.PropertySet = $PropertySet
            }
            $SfSearchFilter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderSchema]::DisplayName,$fldArray[$lint]) 
            $findFolderResults = $service.FindFolders($tfTargetFolder.Id,$SfSearchFilter,$fvFolderView) 
            if ($findFolderResults.TotalCount -gt 0){ 
                foreach($folder in $findFolderResults.Folders){ 
                    $tfTargetFolder = $folder                
                } 
            } 
            else{ 
                Write-host ("Error Folder Not Found check path and try again")  
                $tfTargetFolder = $null  
                break  
            }     
        }  
        if($tfTargetFolder -ne $null){
            return [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]$tfTargetFolder
        }
        else{
            throw ("Folder Not found")
        }
    }
}


####################### 
<# 
.SYNOPSIS 
 Creates a Folder in a Mailbox using the  Exchange Web Services API 

.DESCRIPTION 
  Creates a Folder in a Mailbox using the  Exchange Web Services API 

  Requires the EWS Managed API from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42951

.EXAMPLE
    Example 1 To create a Folder named test in the Root of the Mailbox
     Create-Folder -Mailboxname mailbox@domain.com -NewFolderName test

    Example 2 To create a Folder as a SubFolder of the Inbox
     Create-Folder -Mailboxname mailbox@domain.com -NewFolderName test -ParentFolder '\Inbox'

     Example 3 To create a new Folder Contacts SubFolder of the Contacts Folder
     Create-Folder -Mailboxname mailbox@domain.com -NewFolderName test -ParentFolder '\Contacts' -FolderClass IPF.Contact

#> 
########################
function Create-Folder{
    param( 
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$MailboxName,
        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)] [PSCredential]$Credentials,
        [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true)] [String]$NewFolderName,
        [Parameter(Position=3, Mandatory=$false)] [String]$ParentFolder,
        [Parameter(Position=4, Mandatory=$false)] [String]$FolderClass
    )  
    Begin
     {
        $service = Connect-Exchange -MailboxName $MailboxName -Credentials $Credentials
        $NewFolder = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder($service)  
        $NewFolder.DisplayName = $NewFolderName 
        if(([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($folderClass))){
            $NewFolder.FolderClass = "IPF.Note"
        }
        else{
            $NewFolder.FolderClass = $folderClass
        }
        $EWSParentFolder = $null
        if(([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($ParentFolder))){
            # Bind to the MsgFolderRoot folder  
            $folderid= new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::MsgFolderRoot,$MailboxName)   
            $EWSParentFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)
        }
        else{
            $EWSParentFolder =  Get-FolderFromPath -MailboxName $MailboxName -service $service -FolderPath $ParentFolder
        }
        #Define Folder Veiw Really only want to return one object  
        $fvFolderView = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(1)  
        #Define a Search folder that is going to do a search based on the DisplayName of the folder  
        $SfSearchFilter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderSchema]::DisplayName,$NewFolderName)  
        #Do the Search  
        $findFolderResults = $service.FindFolders($EWSParentFolder.Id,$SfSearchFilter,$fvFolderView)  
        if ($findFolderResults.TotalCount -eq 0){  
            Write-host ("Folder Doesn't Exist")  
            $NewFolder.Save($EWSParentFolder.Id)  
            Write-host ("Folder Created")  
        }  
        else{  
            Write-error ("Folder already Exist with that Name")  
        }  


     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try your solution as fast as possible.

Comment: The Powershell script is really cool. I imported the module but unfortunately I received an error when I try this: `Create-Folder -Mailboxname mailbox@mydomain.com -NewFolderName PStest -ParentFolder '\Contacts' -FolderClass IPF.Contact`

Comment: This are the error `PSCredential : Unable to find type [PSCredential]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.`. Seems like I have to load one more module?

Comment: Ok, I finally get it running. It only works in the Powershell (not Exchange Mangement Shell) and you need to have FullAccess permissions to the Mailbox. Also this lines have to be modified `$ExchangeVersion = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::ExchangeVERSION-OF-THE-EXCHANGE-SERVER` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeversion(v=exchg.80).aspx and the line `$uri=[system.URI] "https://owa.URL-TO-THE-SERVER/ews/exchange.asmx"`. Now everything works fine. Thanks again for this great help. :)

Comment: @Glen, This was really useful. I couldn't figure this out, and it's been causing problems in multiple applications. I almost wish EWS didn't default to the primary mailbox and forced you to know and specify which mailbox you want to create the folder in.